# How to convert this curl command into java command

Tags: java, curl

i need to convert the following curl command into java command.

```
curl https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx"
```

I writed this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me").openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.getOutputStream().write("LOGIN".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    con.getInputStream();
}
```

but I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1915)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at testiamo.main(testiamo.java:18)
```

Comment: Try `HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me").openConnection();` (`import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `Apache HttpClient`

And perform the call this way:

```java
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me");
        postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");

        // You could also send something through JSON...
        if(requestBody != null)
        {
            postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            StringEntity jsonEntity = new StringEntity(requestBody);
            postRequest.setEntity(jsonEntity);
        }

        // Getting the response
        HttpResponse rawResponse = client.execute(postRequest);
        final int status = rawResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        // If status == 200 then we get the response (which could be JSON, XML and so on) and save it as a string.
        if(status == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    rawResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            reader.close();
            client.close();
        }
        else
        {
            client.close();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while doing call!\nStatus: "+ status);
        }
```

For more info, click [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13).

Comment: I get this error:
ago 04, 2021 10:30:17 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: li_gc=MTswOzE2MjgwNjU4MTc7MjswMjFHaojFfu7ZrccbD2V9NU7pLUJlhg+my7cV7lmf3L/aRg==; Domain=.linkedin.com; Expires=Fri, 21 Jul 2023 00:02:44 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 21 Jul 2023 00:02:44 GMT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while doing call!
Status: 401
 at testiamo.main(testiamo.java:47)

Process finished with exit code

Comment: The question as has been asked above has been answered since the call is performed and you get as a response the **HTTP STATUS 401**. That error code means that you are unauthorized. If you need help regarding this error, I would suggest asking another specific question and put all the details in there. I will gladly help. 

https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: Thanks, I have just asked another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648697/apache-httpclient-unauthorized