# Apache HTTPClient unauthorized

Tags: java, curl

I have to write the equivalend of this curl command in java ( that works ):

```
curl https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx"
```

I am using this code:

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class testiamo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me");
        postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxx");

        // Getting the response
        HttpResponse rawResponse = client.execute(postRequest);
        final int status = rawResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        // If status == 200 then we get the response (which could be JSON, XML and so on) and save it as a string.
        if(status == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    rawResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            reader.close();
            client.close();
        }
        else
        {
            client.close();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while doing call!\nStatus: "+ status);
        }


    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
ago 04, 2021 10:30:17 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: li_gc=MTswOzE2MjgwNjU4MTc7MjswMjFHaojFfu7ZrccbD2V9NU7pLUJlhg+my7cV7lmf3L/aRg==; Domain=.linkedin.com; Expires=Fri, 21 Jul 2023 00:02:44 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Fri, 21 Jul 2023 00:02:44 GMT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while doing call!
Status: 401
    at testiamo.main(testiamo.java:47)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```java
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me");

postRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json");
postRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + YOUR_TOKEN);
```

And then try to do the request.

I am supposing the request is a **POST** request. But if that is not the case, then do a GET Request using the same way:

```java
CloseableHttpClient client= HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
        .build();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
getRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + YOUR_TOKEN);
```

Then the steps to get the response are the same.

**UPDATE**

After checking the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api), the request should be a GET request. So use the second snippet of code above.

Good Luck!

Comment: I get this error:
ago 04, 2021 12:09:25 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: li_gc=MTswOzE2MjgwNzE3NjU7MjswMjEiBY4np8T9xEJYQizmAPMhvcIIFo2Ra8y5RrtbZiYizA==; Domain=.linkedin.com; Expires=Thu, 20 Jul 2023 06:34:32 GMT; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 20 Jul 2023 06:34:32 GMT

Comment: I updated my answer
Try doing the above implementation

Answer (score 2):

Java's HTTP client doesn't handle the RFC spec for cookies well. You can switch to the standard spec like so:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
   .create()
   .setDefaultRequestConfig(
      RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()
   )
   .build();
```

Comment: I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while doing call!
Status: 404
 at testiamo.main(testiamo.java:59)

Process finished with exit code 1